# undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: boost, g++

I have installed libboost, why the compilation will report an error.

```bash
amov@amov:~$ locate libboost_system.so
/usr/lib/libboost_system.so
/usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.60.0
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.60.0
amov@amov:~$ g++ -o example example.cc -lboost_system
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccaVHCGA.o: in function `main':
example.cc:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccaVHCGA.o: in function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
example.cc:(.text+0x1f2): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/bin/ld: example.cc:(.text+0x1fe): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/bin/ld: example.cc:(.text+0x20a): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccaVHCGA.o: in function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
example.cc:(.text._ZN5boost6system10error_codeC2Ev[_ZN5boost6system10error_codeC5Ev]+0x1b): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

..................................................
I have tried `g++ -o example example.cc -L/usr/lib -lboost_system`, and it works,but i don't want  to use `-L/usr/lib`.

Comment: ¿Why are there two `libboost_system.so` files? Did you pollute system folders by executing something like `sudo make install` by any chance?

Comment: it's a link:  `amov@amov:~$ ll /usr/lib | grep libboost
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       33 6月  27 22:05 libboost_system.so -> /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       40 6月  27 22:05 libboost_system.so.1.60.0 -> /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.60.0*`